# The method route() is undefined for the type RestDefinition

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

@Component
public class BookRoute extends RouteBuilder {

```
private final Environment env;

public BookRoute(Environment env) {
    this.env = env;
}

public void configure() throws Exception {

    restConfiguration()
            .contextPath(env.getProperty("camel.component.servlet.mapping.contextPath", "/rest/*"))
            .apiContextPath("/api-doc")
            .apiProperty("api.title", "Spring Boot Camel Postgres Rest API.")
            .apiProperty("api.version", "1.0")
            .apiProperty("cors", "true")
            .apiContextPath("doc-api")
            .port(env.getProperty("server.port", "8080"))
            .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

    rest("/book")
            .consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .get("/{name}").route()
            .to("{{route.findBookByName}}")
            .endRest()
            .get("/").route()
            .to("{{route.findAllBooks}}")
            .endRest()
            .post("/").route()
            .marshal().json()
            .unmarshal(getJacksonDataFormat(Book.class))
            .to("{{route.saveBook}}")
            .endRest()
            .delete("/{bookId}").route()
            .to("{{route.removeBook}}")
            .end();

    from("{{route.findBookByName}}")
            .log("Received header : ${header.name}")
            .bean(BookService.class, "findBookByName(${header.name})");

    from("{{route.findAllBooks}}")
            .bean(BookService.class, "findAllBooks");


    from("{{route.saveBook}}")
            .log("Received Body ${body}")
            .bean(BookService.class, "addBook(${body})");


    from("{{route.removeBook}}")
            .log("Received header : ${header.bookId}")
            .bean(BookService.class, "removeBook(${header.bookId})");
}

private JacksonDataFormat getJacksonDataFormat(Class<?> unmarshalType) {
    JacksonDataFormat format = new JacksonDataFormat();
    format.setUnmarshalType(unmarshalType);
    return format;
}
```

}

Above Code is working fine with "<camel.version>3.3.0</camel.version>" but when I change the version to
"<camel.version>4.0.0-M3</camel.version>" I am getting error for ".route()" method in routebuilder class saying "The method route() is undefined for the type RestDefinition"
how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

See the Camel upgrade guides about the changes in rest-dsl from 3.16 onwards
https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3x-upgrade-guide-3_16.html#_rest_dsl